# post call for complex schema mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, post, mongoose

want to know how to make a proper post request for a complex model

```
app.post('/tree',(req,res)=>{
    var tree = new Tree({
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        middleName: req.body.middleName,
        lastName: req.body.lastName,
        alias:  [],
        father: req.body.father,
        mother: req.body.mother,
        relationship: [
            {
                 relation: req.body.relation,
                 children: []
            }
        ]
    });
})
```

this is the schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;

var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength:1,
        trim:true
    },
    middleName: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
     },
     lastName: {
         type: String,
         trim: true
     },
     alias:  [String],
     father: ObjectId,
     mother: ObjectId,
    relationship: [
        {
            relation: ObjectId,
            children: [ObjectId]
        }
    ]    
 });

 var Tree = mongoose.model('Tree',schema);

 module.exports = {Tree};
```

im new to programming so im sorry if its a silly question.
hope the details i provied is sufficient to get a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to **save** your `tree` you can use the `save()` function, like this `tree.save()`. After the change, it will look like this

```
app.post('/tree',(req,res)=>{
    var tree = new Tree({
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        middleName: req.body.middleName,
        lastName: req.body.lastName,
        alias:  [],
        father: req.body.father,
        mother: req.body.mother,
        relationship: [
            {
                 relation: req.body.relation,
                 children: []
            }
        ]
    });
    tree.save().then(err => {
      if (err) return res.send(500); // Error while saving

      res.send(201); // Return status code Created => Success
    });
})
```

*Note: You send a POST request to your http(s) server, not to MongoDb*

Comment: How to add data to alias and children?

Comment: You do the same thing. You create or find (with `Tree.find()`) your object like you did, then you update it and finally you use `save` on that

Comment: Can u show me an example?   By adding two children to the post?

Comment: Sure. Here's an example from MongoDb's [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/). `db.people.update(
   { name: "Andy" },
   { name: "Andy", rating: 1, score: 1 },{ upsert: true })`

Comment: Can u give an example for my post??

Comment: I just gave you a working answer, another example and a link to the docs